# FAILED Building Apk in React Native

Tags: visual-studio-code, react-native

I've got this error when I try to build apk file with ./gradlew bundleRelease

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseResources'.
>
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > Android resource linking failed
> > C:\Users\Yoan\React Native\new\app\android\app\build\intermediates\bundle_manifest\release\processReleaseManifest\bundle-manifest\AndroidManifest.xml:13:
> > AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka
> > com.hotelmaids:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
>
> ```
>  C:\Users\Yoan\React Native\new\app\android\app\build\intermediates\bundle_manifest\release\processReleaseManifest\bundle-manifest\AndroidManifest.xml:13:
> ```
>
> AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka
> com.hotelmaids:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.

I delete those folders. I found somewhere that people and console say they are duplicated and I had another errors

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this command before your APK build:

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res --verbose`

and then delete the raw + drawable-.. folders.

dont delete mipmap folders!